# Terminal Editing File to Remove Certain Characters

Tags: terminal

I have a couple of files which have a format of something like this:

```
TCTCTGGAAAGGGACGCCTGGGAGG   10
AAAAATACATTCTAACCTCGGCGT    1
TAATTTCATCAATATATCAATG  1
(etc...)
```

I want to remove everything after the space so that I only get this in the end:

```
TCTCTGGAAAGGGACGCCTGGGAGG
AAAAATACATTCTAACCTCGGCGT
TAATTTCATCAATATATCAATG
(etc...)
```

How would I do this?

Comment: Should we assume that you have standard Unix tools such as sed, awk, perl, etc? And when you say that you want to remove everything "after" the space, do you mean "after and including"?

Comment: Yes everything after and including the space. Also I have all standard Unix tools.

Answer (score 2):

You can do this with awk:

```
cat oldfile | awk '{print $1}' > newfile
```

Comment: So all of these methods will return the new file with the spaces and the numbers removed right?

Comment: yes, newfile will contain only the strings from the beginning of the line

Answer (score 2):

```
cut -d' ' -f1 file.txt
```

or:

```
sed 's/ .*//' file.txt
```

or

```
sed -e 's/[^ACTG]//g' file.txt
```

or

```
awk '{print $1}' file.txt
```

Comment: So all of these methods will return the new file with the spaces and the numbers removed right?

Answer (score 0):

Not as concise and pretty as timos's answer :), but another quick example of the same functionality but written in Ruby.

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby

data = File.read("data.txt")
f = File.open("outData.txt", "w")
finalData = data.scan(/^\w+/)
finalData.each {|i| f.write(i + "\n")}
f.close
```

Comment: So all of these methods will return the new file with the spaces and the numbers removed right?

Comment: Hi Bucco, yes the following code will do as you require in your question.  If you have a file containing lots of lines of something like "TCTCTGGAAAGGGACGCCTGGGAGG   10" it will parse them to a file called outData.txt and will contain only the DNA data